# Liberty profile: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath in a JAX-RS 2.0 client request

Tags: jax-rs, keystore, websphere-liberty

After upgrading to last version of WAS Liberty Profile, our JAX-RS cliente request to IBM Weather API does not work anymore. (Liberty version 17.0.0.1). I remember I had trouble configuring the certificate repository in server.xml, but it was working OK. Any ideas what I'm missing or may have been changed in Liberty? (Or just how to configure the defaultKeyStore keyStore?)

```
    [3/16/17 23:42:33:426 CET] 000002f0 com.servengine.ws.rs.ThrowableExceptionMapper                E Exception javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://ID_PWD@twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/29.06294/-13.59026/forecast/daily/10day.json?units=m&language=es: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath. handled by ThrowableExceptionMapper
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://ID_PWD@twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/29.06294/-13.59026/forecast/daily/10day.json?units=m&language=es: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.checkClientException(AbstractClient.java:624)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.preProcessResult(AbstractClient.java:606)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doResponse(WebClient.java:1098)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1035)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:892)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1547)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1542)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.get(WebClient.java:1462)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.InvocationBuilderImpl.get(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:80)
    at com.servengine.weather.IBMInsights4WeatherRESTClient.getJsonObject(IBMInsights4WeatherRESTClient.java:86)
    at com.servengine.weather.IBMInsights4WeatherRESTClient.getForecastDaily10Day(IBMInsights4WeatherRESTClient.java:92)
    at com.servengine.weather.IBMInsights4WeatherRESTClient$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getForecastDaily10Day(Unknown Source)
    at com.servengine.eliza.tourism.ws.rs.app.OrganizationServiceResource.getForecastDaily10Day(OrganizationServiceResource.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer.serviceInvoke(JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:659)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:115)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:210)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:381)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:124)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.endpoint.AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.invoke(AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.java:134)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.handleRequest(IBMRestServlet.java:149)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.doGet(IBMRestServlet.java:115)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1157)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://ID_PWD@twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/29.06294/-13.59026/forecast/daily/10day.json?units=m&language=es: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor110.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1377)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1361)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:651)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:693)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1034)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:3)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:213)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.C.a(C.java:339)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.C.a(C.java:248)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:291)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:217)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.C.r(C.java:373)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.C.a(C.java:352)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:752)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.i(as.java:338)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:711)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.startHandshake(as.java:454)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:182)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:20)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1561)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1489)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:491)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:332)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1578)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1607)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1551)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1348)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:322)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ay.checkServerTrusted(ay.java:3)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:588)
    ... 80 more
```

Comment: Would you be able to share how SSL configuration look like in server.xml file? Does the trust store has the signer certificate for the server? HandshakeException indicates problem with trust.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the signed certificate of 
https://ID_PWD@twcservice.mybluemix.net
to your truststore.

#### How to manage your truststore:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html

#### Import that certificate

1. download the certificate
2. import it into the configured truststore by

   `keytool -import -alias YOUR_ALIAS -file YOUR-DONWLOADED_CERTIFICATE.cer - keystore YOUR-LIBERTY-TRUSTSTORE`

keytool is a binary, found in your JDK/bin path